# Calculate position of box-shadow after rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

When putting shadows on rotated elements with CSS, the shadow depends on the rotation of the element. [Here's an example:](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ybr7/)

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: #BBF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
#box1 {
  top: 20px;
}
#box2 {
  top: 170px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
}
#box3 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
```

Is it possible to calculate where the shadow should fall after the rotation, so that the shadow appears to come from the same light source on all elements? I'm assuming I'd have to do it with javascript or server-side, which is fine.

Comment: I like it - sounds like a fun challenge. I don't have time to write a full answer but imagine the lightsource's position with an x, y *and* z value. Then also consider the z values for all your boxes. (z-value being height above document). It's really easy maths from there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer here: [Keep box-shadow direction consistent while rotating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102375/1811992), you can do this in *CSS only* using transforms and pseudo elements.
The point is that the transforms origin moves with the element in chained transforms. here is your example with the same shadow direction for all the elements:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px; height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; left: 5px;
  width: 190px; height: 90px;
  background-color: #888;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBF;
}

#box1 { top: 20px; }
#box1:before { transform: translate(10px, 10px); }

#box2 { top: 170px; transform: rotate(20deg); }
#box2:before { transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(10px, 10px) rotate(20deg); }

#box3 { top: 80px; left: 250px; transform: rotate(120deg); }
#box3:before { transform: rotate(-120deg) translate(10px, 10px) rotate(120deg); }
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

To replicate the shadow somewhat the same on all elements, rotated or not, I ended up using the following:

```
var shadowOffset = 13;
var shadowX = Math.round(Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * shadowOffset, 2);
var shadowY = Math.round(Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * shadowOffset, 2);
```

Which fits into box-shadows parameters like this:

```
$("#box2").css({ "box-shadow": shadowX + "px " + shadowY + "px 5px #888" });
```

And here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ybr7/1/

It's not perfect, especially on small elements where the shadow would've been positioned between two pixels, but it sort of works.

Comment: What's the significance of the 13?

Comment: @Olson.dev That's just the shadows offset. Compare the JSFiddle linked to this one http://jsfiddle.net/3Ybr7/2/ and you'll notice that I've replaced 13 with 45, and the shadows are further from the objects. I'll edit my answer to show that a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a `convertOffset` function that takes x and y shadow coordinates and degrees, and returns the new x/y coordinates to match the rotation. Not only does this work with any shadow position, but it also supports inset shadows. Try editing the below snippet and experimenting with different values.

```js
var xOffset = -4;
var yOffset = 5;
var blurSpreadColor = '4px 0 #222';
var inset = false;

for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  var el = document.getElementById('div' + i);
  var degrees = (i - 1) * 26;
  var offset = convertOffset(xOffset, yOffset, degrees);

  el.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
  el.style.boxShadow = (inset ? 'inset ' : '') + offset[0] + 'px ' + offset[1] + 'px ' + blurSpreadColor;
}

function convertOffset(x, y, deg) {
  var radians = deg * Math.PI / 180;
  var sin = Math.sin(radians);
  var cos = Math.cos(radians);

  return [
    Math.round((x * cos + y * sin) * 100) / 100,
    Math.round((-x * sin + y * cos) * 100) / 100
  ];
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 35px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="div1"></div>
<div class="box" id="div2"></div>
<div class="box" id="div3"></div>
<div class="box" id="div4"></div>
<div class="box" id="div5"></div>
```