# How can I use a box-shadow on an element that also uses transform: rotate?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am using [David Walsh's flipping animation](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) for an info card and it is working great, but I am having trouble adding a box shadow to it. For some reason the CSS3 transition causes the box shadow to have a white outline:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is a Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/hannahwmoore/m3bjz5jn/

Comment: What browser? The artifact in the screenshot is not visible in my browser.

Comment: Me too. Checked in Google Chrome and everything works as expected

Comment: Really? That is bizarre. I am using chrome 61.0. I am not seeing it in IE of FF.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to hopefully make it more visible:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/hannahwmoore/m3bjz5jn/

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Yes seriously, clear caches, reboot and maybe reinstall and reset chrome settings.

Comment: its Perfactly working in firefox

Comment: Working fine on Chrome 62

Comment: Thanks all! Yes I've tried clearing the cache and everything, but I am still seeing it. I guess I will just hope that it is only happening for me. Feeling a little crazy over here...

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102216/keep-box-shadow-direction-consistent-while-rotating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was such a strange bug. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome and now it works fine. There must have been some issue with the installation I had before.