# How to stop box-shadow rotating along with the element on hover without extra div besides the main element div?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I would like to add rotation on my circular elements on hover. I have added it without any hustle. Apparently box-shadow of the corresponding element rotating along on hover. I do not have any extra div. I would like to keep the box-shadow at its place even on hover or otherwise. Any help would be appreciable.

HTML

```
 <div *ngIf="deleteicon" [routerLink]="['/home/add-edit-customer']" title="Delete Selected Customer" class="red-box box">
    <img src="assets/bin.svg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-div .box {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    top: -22px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 6px -6px #777;
    transition: .4s;
}

.container-div .box:hover {
    /* transform: translateY(4px); */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: could you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: sure. The codes are added now.

Answer (score 0):

For demo sake, I'm taking the liberty to remove `.container-div` from both `.container-div .box` since your code sample doesn't have any `.container-div`. Feel free to add it back if your original code does contain `container-div` class.

If you want to keep the `box-shadow` still while rotating you might want to add `translate(-10px, -1px) rotate(-360deg);` on `transform: rotate(360deg)`

If you would like to keep the `box-shadow` at its place even on hover you just need to add the `box-shadow: 4px 6px 6px -6px #777;` style on `.box:hover` too.

In reverse if you want to remove the `box-shadow` you need to add `box-shadow: none;`

See the following snippet:

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    top: -22px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 6px -6px #777;
    transition: .4s;
}
 
.box:hover {
    /* transform: translateY(4px); */
    box-shadow: 4px 6px 6px -6px #777; /* << add if you want to show box-shadow on hover 
    box-shadow: none; /* << add if you want to remove box-shadow on hover */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-10px, -1px) rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(-10px, -1px) rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="deleteicon" [routerLink]="['/home/add-edit-customer']" title="Delete Selected Customer" class="red-box box">
    <img src="assets/bin.svg">
</div>
```

For more info into [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), you could check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

For more info about [Transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin), you could check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) or [similar box-shadow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102216/keep-box-shadow-direction-consistent-while-rotating)

Comment: The box-shadow rotated along with the element even after i have added the box-shadow property on .box:hover as you said.  I want the shadow to be fixed in a place.  But box-shadow:none property is also informative. I should consider that if could not keep the shadow at a fixed place.

Comment: I tried to add one more option if you want to keep it still while rotating @SandyB

Comment: Your second option is completely remove the box-shadow on hover which is actually not what i wanted. But i go with it if nothing comes up

Comment: have you see the update with translate and rotate in snippet? @SandyB

Answer (score 0):

One way to try it would be deleting "box-shadow" from rotating element and creating a second element under the one rotating with same "box-shadow" options that stays still all the time

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that solution from web. I got a lot elements on my project that i want to apply the rotation effect on hovering . So i had to go through all of them  in order to add an extra element i guess.

Comment: you can just create one class ".shadows" for all underlying "box-shadows" and then use JS to input them into your HTML at the places that contain the rotation effect using js or jQuery if doing it manually is too much work.