# css rotation animation with drop shadow

Tags: html, css, animation

I am working on a css animation that rotate a svg with shadow.
my code was like

```
<svg class="rotate shadow" />
```

```
@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
.rotate{
    animation: rotation 30s infinite linear;
}
.shadow{
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 5px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.4));
}
```

but if I doing this, the shadow rotate too.

Is there any way to only rotate the svg and render the shadow after?

Comment: Hi, you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102216/keep-box-shadow-direction-consistent-while-rotating
You need to render the shadow on another element make both rotate at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest way to do that, is use [positions CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) - relative parent should hold children in the same X Y coord, then you can put shadow under your svg and both elements are not depend of each other.

Then you can make shadow depend of your svg

```css
@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
.rotate{
    animation: rotation 30s infinite linear;
}
.shadow{
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 5px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.4));
}
.parent{
  position:relative;
}
.parent > svg {
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <svg class="shadow" width="100" height="100">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:#fff" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="rotate" width="100" height="100">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```